Как пользоваться бесплатным планом Cypress, чтобы смотреть подробные результаты тестов?
Подскажите пожалуйста. Использую Cypress v13.7.2 для написания автотестов. Сейчас у нас ежедневно прогоняется более 100 тестов и быстро заканчивается место в Cypress cloud. Появляется вверху экрана текст:

Plan Limit Reached: You've reached 131% of your test results  for this
usage period.


Возможно ли его как-то чистить?
В бесплатном плане указано что входит просмотр результатов тестов и в документации указаны скриншоты, где тесты с подробной информацией


Я пока не могу найти нужного решения. Все что приходит на ум, это переходить к каждому тесту и отправлять его в архив. Это очень долго и совсем не решение.
